# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer stops working after first No from ShouldBegin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` and custom delegate to decide whether gesture should start. Everything work just fine before `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` return `No`. After than delegate continue getting called for `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` but gesture doesn't start independently of result.

I've trying to call `reset()` and to remove and re-add gesture recognizer to the view, but it doesn't work.

I have really no idea how to proceed, any directions are really appreciated.

P.S. I found that focusing `UITextView` causes that - after focusing and unfocusing `UITextView` gesture stops working. But I still have no idea of what's the root reason.

I've made a simple repro app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IYPDdKILBxFCrjV3-RjrnerXPoWT0RQJ/view?usp=sharing

That's the code sample:

```cs
public class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var pan = new UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(HandlePan)
        {
            Edges = UIRectEdge.Left,
            Delegate = new InteractivePopGestureDelegate()
        };
        View.AddGestureRecognizer(pan);
    }

    private void HandlePan(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"HandlePan: {recognizer.State}"); // This stop being called after focusing Editor on page.
    }

    private class InteractivePopGestureDelegate : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    {
        public override bool ShouldBegin(UIGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ShouldBegin"); // This gets called as expected.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, if you could share some code or a sample project link to explain that, it will be helpful to check how to solve that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I've added link to the repro app.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have found a solution, will update in answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the shared code not works, but I know that using `AddTarget` for **UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer** can make it works. You could have a try.

The sample code:

```
public class ModalPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var pan = new UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer();
        pan.Edges = UIRectEdge.Left;
        pan.AddTarget(() => HandlePan(pan));
        View.AddGestureRecognizer(pan);
    }

    private void HandlePan(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"HandlePan: {recognizer.State}"); // This stop being called after focusing Editor on page.

        if(recognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ShouldBegin");
        }

        #region Just to make something happen on the UI
        // Following lines could be totally ignored / removed.
        // Just to make it visible on the UI.
        Color fadeColor = Color.FromRgb(122, 85, 191);

        nfloat Fade(double component, nfloat opacity) => (nfloat) (1d - opacity * (1d - component));

        var point = recognizer.LocationInView(recognizer.View);
        if (recognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed)
        {
            var opacity = point.X / recognizer.View.Frame.Width;
            recognizer.View.BackgroundColor =
                UIColor.FromRGB(
                    Fade(fadeColor.R, opacity),
                    Fade(fadeColor.G, opacity),
                    Fade(fadeColor.B, opacity));
        }
        else if (recognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended ||
                 recognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled)
        {
            recognizer.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly, I should be thinking of trying this, as I'm doging for other gesture recognizers which doesn't even have option to pass handler in ctor..